# Non-numeric character in statement label at (1) and Invalid character in name at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I wrote these following lines in fortran

```
p48=-18351._8*n**10-89784._8*n**9-210021._8*n**8-271638._8*n**7-219369._8*n**6-90572._8*n**5-26491._8*n**4-7790._8*n**3-1992._8*n**2-&
2760._8*n-2160._8
p49=165._8*n**10+825._8*n**9+109664._8*n**8+331682._8*n**7+457641._8*n**6+346145._8*n**5+219290._8*n**4+86724._8*n**3+13608._8*n**2+&
14256._8*n+10368._8
```

and I define these two characters as real(8) and I recieved the following errors

```
2760._8*n-2160._8
 1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)

2760._8*n-2160._8
  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: are you sure that the line is not already too long when you decide to add the ampersand for continuation?

Comment: Always use tag fortran.

Comment: Could you try the compiler option `-ffree-line-length-none` and see if the problem persists? If not, @Jean-FrançoisFabre gave you the answer.

Comment: I haven't coded in FORTRAN for 25 years and will continue to do so :)

Comment: the first line is 134 char, default max for free form fortran is 132.  Personally I'd shorten the line by by moving the `&` rather than rely on a compiler flag to make it work.

Comment: FORTRAN is pretty old but Fortran is not so (note the small letters :) Btw, be careful with `n**10` which may easily overflow for 4-byte integer...

Comment: what makes you think `n` is an integer :-)

Comment: @agentp Of course, good old implicit rule :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line truncated, Syntax error in argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194589/line-truncated-syntax-error-in-argument-list)