# Wline-truncation error

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to write large number of elements in a single row using-

```
        write(*,1) a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m
   1    format(13(1pe11.4,1x))
```

But It is showing an error that line is truncated at `k`. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is it showing exactly? Show all the details you have. Please also use tag [tag:fortran] to all Fortran questions. Please [edit] the question to a better shape. Include your compilation commands and the error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line truncated, Syntax error in argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194589/line-truncated-syntax-error-in-argument-list)

Answer (score 0):

gfortran has a `-ffixed-line-length-n` directive, where `n` you can replace with a value that is at least the maximum number of characters you have at that particular line in your code.