# Invalid or Missing Repeat Count in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am writing a Fortran program to read data from 35 files with similar size(8 columns and 8784 lines in each file) and write to a single file. I wrote the following code and when compiling "Invalid or missing repeat count" error is appearing.

```
Program Basic
implicit none
Character*20,dimension(35)::filename(/'1979.txt','1980.txt','1981.txt','1982.txt','1983.txt','1984.txt','1985.txt','1986.txt','1987.txt','1988.txt','1989.txt','1990.txt','1991.txt','1992.txt','1993.txt','1994.txt','1995.txt','1996.txt','1997.txt','1998.txt','1999.txt','2000.txt','2001.txt','2002.txt','2003.txt','2004.txt','2005.txt','2006.txt','2007.txt','2008.txt','2009.txt','2010.txt','2011.txt','2012.txt','2013.txt'/)

real,dimension(1:8784)::Db,Dp,WS
integer,dimension(1:8784)::a,b,c,d,SR
integer::i,file

do file=1,35
  open(7000,file=filename(file))
  open(7001,file='Final.txt')

do i=1,8784
 read(7000,*)a(i),b(i),c(i),d(i),Db(i),Dp(i),WS(i),SR(i)
 write(7001,*)a(i),b(i),c(i),d(i),Db(i),Dp(i),WS(i),SR(i)
   end do
  end do
end Program Basic
```

The output from the compiler (Silverfrost FTN95) is

```
Runtime error from program:c:\users\aadhikari2\desktop\trial 1\freeformat1.exe
Run-time Error *** Error 62, Invalid or missing repeat count BASIC - in file freeformat1.f95 at line 19 [+0325]
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Add a specific version where need to specify (not here). Fortran 90 is just one old version.

Comment: Your line is simply too long. But please, next time be sure to show the complete error message. Your indentation is also misleading.

Comment: I am using Silverfrost FTN95 and I am new to Fortran programing. Complete error message is as follows.   "Runtime error from program:c:\users\aadhikari2\desktop\trial 1\freeformat1.exe
Run-time Error
 *** Error   62, Invalid or missing repeat count

 BASIC -  in file freeformat1.f95 at line 19 [+0325]

Comment: I did not find a good duplicate target. There is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194589/line-truncated-syntax-error-in-argument-list but there are more problems in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration line

```
Character*20,dimension(35)::filename(...
```

is too long for free form Fortran (see [Line truncated, Syntax error in argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194589/line-truncated-syntax-error-in-argument-list) ). You must split the line.

But also the array declaration is not syntactically correct. You should use the `=` assignment as in

```
Character*20,dimension(35) :: filename = (/'1979.txt','1980.txt','1981.txt', &
                      '1982.txt','1983.txt','1984.txt', &
                      '1985.txt','1986.txt','1987.txt', &
                      '1988.txt','1989.txt','1990.txt', &
                      '1991.txt','1992.txt','1993.txt', &
                      '1994.txt','1995.txt','1996.txt', &
                      '1997.txt','1998.txt','1999.txt', &
                      '2000.txt','2001.txt','2002.txt', &
                      '2003.txt','2004.txt','2005.txt', &
                      '2006.txt','2007.txt','2008.txt', &
                      '2009.txt','2010.txt','2011.txt', &
                      '2012.txt','2013.txt'/)
```

Also, don't forget to `close` your files at the end.